# Change button functionality on use

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following question. In my project I have a button which adds a movie to the users watchlist. I want to make it so that when I press it it changes its functionality to "remove from watchlist". How exactly can I make it work? Should I add a Boolean in the database or somehow do it on the front-end?

Here you can find the source code. **https://github.com/kris34/Movies/tree/main/Client/movies-project/src/app/auth/watchlist
**

this is my watchlist component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-watchlist',
  templateUrl: './watchlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./watchlist.component.css'],
})
export class WatchlistComponent {
  watchlist: IMovie[] | null = [];

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private api: ApiService) {
    this.getWatchlist();
  }

  getWatchlist() {
    this.api.loadUserWatchlist().subscribe({
      next: (v) => {
        this.watchlist = v;
        console.log(this.watchlist);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

So far I haven't tried anything.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code, in the code shared on this site, that adds anything to the watchlist. Please read [ask]; we need to know more about how your site currently works to give you advice on how to make it work the way you want.

Comment: You would have to add a boolean for every single movie, so that's not practical. Since you have the watchlist already you just need to see if whatever movie in question is contained in that list or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a few methods to your `watchlist.component.ts`. The additional comments below the code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';
import { IMovie } from 'src/app/shared/interfaces/movie';
import { MovieService } from 'src/app/movie/movie.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-watchlist',
  templateUrl: './watchlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./watchlist.component.css'],
})
export class WatchlistComponent {
  watchlist: IMovie[] | null = [];
  isAddedToWatchlist: boolean = false;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private api: ApiService, private movieService: MovieService) {
    this.getWatchlist();
  }

  getWatchlist() {
    this.api.loadUserWatchlist().subscribe({
      next: (v) => {
        this.watchlist = v;
        console.log(this.watchlist);
      },
    });
  }

  toggleWatchlist(movieId: number) {
    if (this.isMovieInWatchlist(movieId)) {
      this.movieService.removeFromWatchlist(movieId).subscribe(() => {
        this.isAddedToWatchlist = false;
      });
    } else {
      this.movieService.addToWatchlist(movieId).subscribe(() => {
        this.isAddedToWatchlist = true;
      });
    }
  }

  isMovieInWatchlist(movieId: number): boolean {
    return this.watchlist ? this.watchlist.some((movie) => movie.id === movieId) : false;
  }
}
```

I added the `isAddedToWatchlist` property, which keeps track of whether the current movie is in the user's watchlist or not.

I created the `toggleWatchlist(movieId: number)` method, which is called when the user clicks the "Add to Watchlist" or "Remove from Watchlist" button. This method will call the appropriate methods (`addToWatchlist` or `removeFromWatchlist`) from the `MovieService` and update the `isAddedToWatchlist` flag accordingly.

I added the `isMovieInWatchlist(movieId: number): boolean` method, which checks whether the given `movieId` is present in the user's watchlist. This method is used to determine whether to display "Add to Watchlist" or "Remove from Watchlist" text on the button.

In your component's template (HTML), you can use Angular's (click) event binding to call the `toggleWatchlist(movieId)` method when the user clicks the button. Additionally, use Angular's data binding with *ngIf to conditionally display the "Add to Watchlist" or "Remove from Watchlist" text based on the value of the `isAddedToWatchlist` property.

And lastly, the HTML button tag:

```
<button (click)="toggleWatchlist(movie.id)">
  {{ isMovieInWatchlist(movie.id) ? 'Remove from Watchlist' : 'Add to Watchlist' }}
</button>
```